# Create mock without constructor invocation

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Is that possible in **RhinoMocks** to create mock object without it constructor invocation?

```
    public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Mock me!");
        }
    } 

    [Test]
    public void TestCtors()
    {
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        A a = (A)mocks.StrictMock(typeof(A));
        Assert.IsTrue(true, "Should be eligible");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need this? The goal of a constructor is to initialize the class members into a usable state.  Why would you want this skipped?

Comment: But I want to _mock_ class, so I do not need it members be initialized. For instance EasyMock do not invoke ctor.

Comment: Rhino.Mocks can't do this as explained by @Steve Haigh.  You might want to check out JustMock from Telerik.  I think it allows default/base ctors to be skipped when creating a mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way around this if you are mocking a concrete class. If you could mock in interface instead that would obviously not call a constructor. Would it be possible to re-work your code so that `A` implements and interface which you can mock?

Comment: No, I can't/wan't change my source code. I wonder why constructor is performing? E.g. in EasyMock it is not!

Comment: I'm not familiar with EasyMock, but if that works for you maybe you can use that instead? The c'tor is firing here because Rhino Mocks creates an instance deriving from your class - see the note at the end of http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Mocking+classes.ashx

Comment: EasyMock is for Java. Thanks never the less.

Comment: Ah, that would be why I have never heard of it :-) Sorry!